# Error output "command size does not match number of interfaces "

Tags: ros2-control

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
- ROS2 Version: Humble
- ros2_control install: used apt

I am writing a custom gpio controller for ros2_control with the purpose of controlling the outputs of some Beckhoff modules. I am using [ICube Robotics' ethercat_driver_ros2 library](https://github.com/ICube-Robotics/ethercat_driver_ros2) to help me do that.

I am getting my hardware to load just fine with my launch file but I am getting this issue where my hardware interfaces don't get claimed by my controller. When I run
`ros2 topic pub /gpio_controller_name/commands std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray "{data: [1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.,0.0,0.0]}" -1` in a seperate terminal, I get the following

```
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1711397485.168228274] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1711397485.173974764] [controller_manager]: 'update_rate' parameter not set, using default value.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.174097572] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.174931224] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.175069373] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.185404659] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.185547473] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'gpio_controller' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.187857939] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'gpio_controller' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.188206601] [EthercatDriver]: gpios
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.191984944] [EthercatDriver]: Got 1 modules
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192009949] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'gpio_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192208647] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'gpio_controller' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192222574] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'gpio_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192233107] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'gpio_controller' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192240987] [EthercatDriver]: Starting ...please wait...
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7000, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7010, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7020, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7030, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7040, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7050, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7060, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] {0, 1, 0x2, 0xaf93052, 0x7070, 0x1}
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397485.192955773] [EthercatDriver]: Activated EcMaster!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.193152401] [EthercatDriver]: updated!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.193192498] [EthercatDriver]: System Successfully started!
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.193205373] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'gpio_controller'
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1711397486.238112133] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Set controller type to "joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster" for joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.238865652] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1711397486.256138690] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.256998383] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.257092705] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1711397486.258023774] [spawner_gpio_controller_name]: Set controller type to "gpio_controller/GPIOController" for gpio_controller_name
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.265344884] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'gpio_controller_name'
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1711397486.276098576] [spawner_gpio_controller_name]: Loaded gpio_controller_name
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1711397486.295536788] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'gpio_controller_name'
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1711397486.296421424] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1711397486.326008024] [spawner_gpio_controller_name]: Configured and activated gpio_controller_name
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 78056]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 78058]
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397851.085253292] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397852.085325901] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397853.095320085] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397854.105215107] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397855.105215163] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397856.105215750] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1711397857.105216389] [gpio_controller_name]: command size (8) does not match number of interfaces (0)
```

Checking to see what is claimed and unclaimed I get

```
probot-linux-pc@probotlinuxpc-XPS-8700:~/dev_ws$ ros2 control list_hardware_components
Hardware Component 1
    name: gpio_controller_name
    type: system
    plugin name: ethercat_driver/EthercatDriver
    state: id=3 label=active
    command interfaces
        gpio_0/dig_output.1 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.2 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.3 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.4 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.5 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.6 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.7 [available] [unclaimed]
        gpio_0/dig_output.8 [available] [unclaimed]
```

I would not be surprised if I am implementing my hardware interface files incorrectly (they are based heavily off of example 10 from the ros2_controls examples). Has anyone faced a similar issue? If so, how did you resolve it?

My config yaml file

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    # joint_state_broadcaster:
    #   type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
      
    gpio_controller_name:
      type: gpio_controller/GPIOController



gpio_controller_name:
  ros__parameters:

    inputs:
      
      - gpio_0/dig_output.1
      - gpio_0/dig_output.2
      - gpio_0/dig_output.3
      - gpio_0/dig_output.4
      - gpio_0/dig_output.5
      - gpio_0/dig_output.6
      - gpio_0/dig_output.7
      - gpio_0/dig_output.8
     

    outputs:
      
      - gpio_0/dig_output.1
      - gpio_0/dig_output.2
      - gpio_0/dig_output.3
      - gpio_0/dig_output.4
      - gpio_0/dig_output.5
      - gpio_0/dig_output.6
      - gpio_0/dig_output.7
      - gpio_0/dig_output.8
```

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR comes from [this line](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/e41ee3153ce54b8177bdec0e88e3d245cb3d7515/example_10/controllers/gpio_controller.cpp#L77). Please add also your controller-yaml, have you set the inputs/outputs parameters?

Comment: just updated the post to include my yaml file

Comment: you specify the same interfaces for input and output? Add debug output [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/e41ee3153ce54b8177bdec0e88e3d245cb3d7515/example_10/controllers/gpio_controller.cpp#L40) and see what the class variable holds (are the parameters successfully parsed or not..)

Comment: I am using the convention from example 10. I believe it does the same thing. I put the debug line as you asked and found both my input_ and output_ class vars have a size of 0. 

I did my parsing as follows:
`outputs_ = get_node()->get_parameter("outputs").as_string_array();`
`inputs_ = get_node()->get_parameter("inputs").as_string_array();`

Comment: I ended up manually doing this part `inputs_.resize(8);` and adding `inputs_[0] = "gpio_0/dig_output.1";` for 1-8. I finally got my LED to turn on! I do not know why the parsing didn't work. If you have any insight I would love to hear it, otherwise I think we are close to being able to closing this inquiry.

Comment: can you try to use only a single string without any special characters (/ or dots). Not sure if this could be the problem [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/e41ee3153ce54b8177bdec0e88e3d245cb3d7515/example_10/controllers/gpio_controller.cpp#L98-L99)